# Got a string with a substring in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to take a string of data from the database by using substring but the results Unknown column 'code' in 'where clause'

Example my string **RS0002030720160003**

I want get **RS0002**

This my controllers

```
public function report(){
    $nomor = $this->input->post('nomor_reseller');

    $report_data = $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor);
    if ($nomor == ""  ) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 
                '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                Nomor atau bulan Harus di isi &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
        redirect('admin/hasil');        
    } elseif ($report_data == NULL  ) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 
                '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                kosong &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
        redirect('admin/hasil');        
    } else {            
        $data=array('title'     =>'KOPKAR - Pelanggan',
                    'report_data'   => $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor),
                    'isi'       =>'admin/hasil'
        );          
        $this->load->view('dashboard/wrapper',$data);   
    }       

}
```

This my views

```
   <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th><div align="center">No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Produk</th>
            <th class="text-center">Jumlah Produk Terjual</th>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
            <th class="text-center"></th>                   
            <th class="text-center">Rp.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</div></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
            $no = 1;            
            foreach ($report_data as $row) {                    
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->id_barcode; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->jumlah; ?></td>
                <td class="fontCap text-center"><?php  ?></td>
                <td class="fontCap text-center"><?php  ?></td>
                <td><div align="center"></div></td>
                <td><div align="center">
                    <a href="#" title="delete" onclick="return confirm('Anda yakin ingin menghapus produk  dengan ID  pada database?');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                    <?php
                    $no++;

            }
                ?>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

This my module

```
function get_data($nomor) {
    $this->db->select('SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 7) as code', false);
    $this->db->from('tb_pelanggan');
    $this->db->where('code',$nomor);    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: any issue you are facing ..??

Answer (score 1):

This barely has anything to do with PHP or the CodeIgniter framework - that's just what you're using to access the database, and the problem is on the database level ...

`WHERE` conditions work on column names, but not on aliases you've put in the `SELECT` portion of a query.
When you want to compare against data that is already selected, you should use `HAVING` instead.

Just replace your `where()` call with an identical `having()` one and it should work.

Comment: I do also believe `CODE` might be a reserved MySQL word.

Comment: @santosh Yes, maybe even more than one thing, but you can't seriously ask me to review code that you've posted as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ..

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 7) as code', false);
    $this->db->where("(SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 7) = '$nomor')"); 
    $this->db->from('tb_pelanggan');

    $A=$this->db->get();
    $query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();
    } else {
    return false;
}
```

Your query is executing like this 
`SELECT SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 5) as code FROM (tb_pelanggan) WHERE SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 5) 'sadsa'`
It should be like 
`SELECT SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 7) as code FROM (tb_pelanggan) WHERE (SUBSTRING(id_barcode, 1, 7) = 'sadsa')`

Comment: nice @santosh, no error but I would expect the data does not appear on views,

Comment: could you explain bit more .. please do update your question.

Comment: `$data['report_data']= $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor);` may this is what are you looking for